# Копирование фотографий из vk.com к себе в альбом

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Используя vkapi.photos.get получаю url фотографии, возможно ли без промежуточного сохранения на локальном компьютере сохранить ее у себя в альбоме

```
photos = vkapi.photos.get(owner_id=owner_id, album_id=album_id, count=1000)
url = photo['photo_604']
```

В vk описан метод [photos.save](https://vk.com/dev/photos.save), но его использование предполагает использование метода [photos.getUploadServer](https://vk.com/dev/photos.getUploadServer). Данный способ предполагает загрузку фотографий. Так же в vk есть [photos.copy](https://vk.com/dev/photos.copy) но его использование не позволяет выбрать альбом. Есть ли способ который позволяет скопировать фотографию с vk.com к себе в заданный альбом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны сохранить копию фотографии в альбом «Сохраненные фотографии» с помощью метода [`photos.copy`](https://vk.com/dev/photos.copy), а затем переместить её оттуда в нужный альбом с помощью метода [`photos.move`](https://vk.com/dev/photos.move).